# How do I add a specific array to an existing document in my database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, discord.js

I'm trying to create a command for my Discord Bot, for adding a `reaction` to a specific `message` linked to a `role` the `user` should receive when reacting with the specified emoji.

The syntax may help to understand it better:

```
!addRoleByReaction <messageID> <emoji you want to add as reaction> <role the user should receive>
```

#### Example:

```
!addRoleByReaction 123456789  987654321
```

> If the user reacts with '' to the `message` with the `ID` '123456789' he'll receive the `role` with the ID '987654321'

---

### Problem:

Currently this is my database schema:

```js
_id: reqString,
    message: [{
        msgId: reqString,
        reactionRole: [{
            reaction: reqString,
            role: reqString,
        }],
    }],
```

*(I'm using [`mongoDB`](https://www.mongodb.com/) and the `npm package` '[`mongoose`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose)')*

After adding the first `reaction` my `database document` looks like this:

[image: First output]

But if I add another `reaction` it looks like this:

[image: Second output]

#### What I actually want...

...is to **push** (if an entry for this `guild` & this `messageID` already exists) a new entry *(containing the **second** or **third**, ... `reaction` & `role`)* into the **`reactionRole`** array.

But right now, as you can see, it adds a new entry with the second `reaction` to the **`message`** array. In general, it is not that bad, but it's just ugly..

Almost forgot: this is how I'm adding new entries to my database:

```js
// 'targetMessage' contains the message ID
// 'targetReaction' contains the reaction to be added
// 'role' contains the ID of the role, the user should receive
// 'mongo()' simply connects to the database

await mongo().then(async mongoose => {
    try {
        await messageReactionSchema.findOneAndUpdate({
            _id: guild.id,
            message: {
                $elemMatch: {
                    msgId: targetMessage,
                },
            },
        }, {
            _id: guild.id,
            $push: {
                message: [{
                    msgId: targetMessage,
                    reactionRole: [{
                        reaction: targetReaction,
                        role,
                    }],
                }],
            },
        }, {
            upsert: true,
        });
    }
    finally {
        mongoose.connection.close();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my problem and avoid further complications, I have now simply adjusted the `schema`:

```js
// _id reflects the id of the message
_id: reqString,
reactionRole: [{
    _id: false,
    reaction: reqString,
    role: reqString,
}]
```

As you can see, I removed the `guild.id` and the `message` array.

Now a new `document` is created for **each message**, containing only the array with all `reactions` and the associated `roles`.

Since the `message ID` is **unique** and a `guild` can also be identified by it, this structure should not create any problems and also makes it **easier** for the program **to find a document** since I now only have to search for the `message ID`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator with `$push` to add role to the target message:

```
await messageReactionSchema.findOneAndUpdate({
  _id: guild.id,
  message: { msgId: targetMessage }
}, {
  $push: {
     "message.$.reactionRole": {
        reaction: targetReaction,
        role,
     },
  },
}...
```

Note:

> If you specify a single query predicate in the `$elemMatch` expression, and are not using the `$not` or `$ne` operators inside of `$elemMatch`, `$elemMatch` can be omitted.

Comment: Sounds good, I'll test this as soon as I'm back home but thanks already!

Comment: And what about the `msgId` field in my `message` array? Because you didn't include that in your answer

Comment: Refer to your code, `msgId` field is not change so you don't need to put it in the update

Comment: If I never add the field to the database, how am I supposed to find a document based on the `guild.id` and `msgId`? The field is then not present, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Oh sorry. I forgot the part that an entry for this `guild` & this `messageID` is not exists. In this case, one query may not be enough.

Comment: Can't I just add the `msgId` field somewhere in your answer?

Comment: Like `$push: { "message.$": targetMessage, "mesage.$.reactionRole": { ... } }`

Comment: I think it's not possible

Comment: Then what should it look like if I need a second `query`? I really do not know how to continue here :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233121/discussion-between-cuong-le-ngoc-and-toasty).